# Elasticsearch query with multiple conditions and time range

Tags: elasticsearch, date-range

I'm trying to create a query to count instances where two conditions are met over the last day.

This query shows the count for the two conditions, but when I try to add a range in, it seems to match all documents:

```
 GET logstash-*/_count
    {
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "should": [
            {
              "match": {
                "rawmsg": {
                "query": "Could not send Message.",
                "type": "phrase"
              }
              }
            },
            {
              "match": {
                "stack_trace": {
                  "query": "*WebServiceException*",
                  "type": "phrase"
                  }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }

}
```

Here's how I'm trying to add the date range:

```
GET logstash-*/_count
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "rawmsg": {
            "query": "Could not send Message.",
            "type": "phrase"
          }
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "stack_trace": {
              "query": "*WebServiceException*",
              "type": "phrase"
              }
          }
        },
        {

          "range" : {
            "@timestamp" : {
                "gte" : "now-1d/d",
                "lt" :  "now/d"
            }
        }
        }
      ]
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I ended up finding two ways of accomplishing what I needed:

```
GET logstash-*/tcp_input/_count?q=stack_trace: *WebServiceException* AND rawmsg: "Could not send Message" AND @timestamp: [ now-30d TO now ]

and

GET logstash-*/_count
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": """stack_trace: *WebServiceException* AND rawmsg: "Could not send Message" AND @timestamp: [  now-3d  TO now]""",
      "analyze_wildcard": true
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using a `should` clause instead of a `must` clause, which effectively combines your conditions with an `OR` instead of an `AND`.

Also the timestamp should be `now/d-1d` for the range query.